# How to program Kenwood TM-742A 6-meter repeater offsets for 500kHz

Tags: repeater, kenwood, radio-programming

All the 6-meter repeaters in my area use a 500kHz offset, but the Kenwood TM-742A defaults to 1MHz offsets. Is there any way to make it easier to program the local repeaters into this radio?

Answer (score 1):

To disable Repeater AutoShift turn the power off. Press and hold both the VFO and REV keys while turning power on. Do this again to turn Autoshift back on.

The manual makes mention of using the SHIFT key to override the autoshift but I am not sure how this works.

I have multiples of this radio and have never had the occasion to need to use a non-standard repeater shift on 6m. No 6m repeaters near me so cannot test. This does however work on the VHF/UHF. In my experience California seems to be the most likely place where repeater shifts are non-standard but having said that, anyone can change repeater shifts.